# CrossCompile Expect to ARM

Tags: tcl, cross-compiling, expect, configure, autoconf

I know this is a duplicate question. But previous threads are not allowing me to add comment to know the hack or update on how to cross compile expect for ARM. Just reposting once again.

I am getting below error, While i am trying to cross compile

`checking if WNOHANG requires _POSIX_SOURCE... configure: error: Expect can't be cross compiled`

Does anyone able to cross compile for ARM? Please share some inputs.

Comment: This might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62765/cross-compiling-expect-for-arm. I would also like to suggest two possible alternatives: 1) setting up an ARM VM in QEMU and compiling Expect in it; 2) looking into [TclX](https://tcl.wiki/207) if the reason you want to Expect is to have its process management commands in Tcl.

Comment: Thank you. Anyways after couple of hacks, now i am able to cross compile to ARM